# How to scrape a variable data from a source code?

Tags: c#, html, hyperlink

I'm trying to scrape a link from the source code of a website that varies with every source code.

Form example:

```
 <div align="center">
    <a href="http://www10.site.com/d/the rest of the link">
        <span class="button_upload green">
```

The next time I get the source code the `http://www10` changes to any `http://www` + number like `http://www65`.

How can I scrape the exact link with the new changed number?

Edit :
Here's how i use RE `MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(textBox6.Text, "(href=\"http://www10)(?<td_inner>.*?)(\">)", RegexOptions.Singleline);`

Comment: Do you use a Html Parser? Like http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: @appl3r i used Regular Expressions but using it i had to enter every new num manually

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in the comments that you use Regulars expressions for parsing the HTML Document. That is a the hardest way you can do this (also, generally not recommended!). Try using a HTML Parser like http://html-agility-pack.net

For HTML Agility Pack: You install it via NuGet Packeges and here is an example (posted on their website):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");
```

It can also load string contents, not just files. You use xPath or CSS Selectors to navigate inside the document and select what you want.

Comment: ok this is a bit cool but , the problem still on cas of the changed num after the www . applying your way means it will scrap all http links but i can make a removal string to remove all static links except my link . will try that and get back to you thanks

Comment: If you make a request with `WebClient client = new WebClient();` you get the source of the page. You scrape the links and store them and you can make the next WebClient request with the url's you just scraped. Also you can almost every time write a selector to select only the links you need.

Comment: i installed the HTML Agility Pack but your code is showing errors 
i'm working on fixing them anyway thanks

Comment: It is the code posted on their website, but looks like it is wrong. Instead of `"//a[@href"]` try `"//a[@href]"`

Comment: here's how i use RE `MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(textBox6.Text, "(href=\"http://www10)(?<td_inner>.*?)(\">)", RegexOptions.Singleline);`

Comment: I suggest you check out some web scraping/crawling tutorial for C#. It should be really easy to download a page and grab a link's content and use it in the next request.

Answer (score 0):

How about a JS function like this, run when the page loads:

```
// jQuery is required!

var updateLinkUrl = function (num) { 
    $.each($('.button_upload.green'), function (pos, el) {
          var orig = $(el).parent().prop("href");
          var newurl = orig.replace("www10", "www" + num);
          $(el).parent().prop("href", newurl);
    });
};
$(document).ready(function () {  updateLinkUrl(65); });
```

Comment: i will try it but the last line in your code the 65 is a variable too i don't know the exact new num that will exist in the new source code

Comment: after second thoughts your code is based on knowing the num after the www which i don't know i'm giving you an example only

Comment: how do we know the number?

Comment: @ GlennFerrie that's my problem but i just noticed it has a div and an id bu using HTML Agility Pack i may be able to scrape it but this will lead to another prob to use HTML Agility Pack i have to make an HtmlWeb but i'm using httpwebrequest method post